# Tracking individual visitors in Wordpress and Google Analytics

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

**Here is what I'd like to achieve:** I have a landing page and a list of contacts. I want to send each of my contacts the link and be able to see the analytics (duration, visitor flow, conversion) for each individual. Most importantly, I just want to confirm they visit the link.

What I'm thinking of doing is using a [Wordpress URL parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to add a unique identifier to the page for each contact, and then track those pages in Google Analytics.

What is the best practice? Is there a better/faster/easier way to do track individual visitors in Wordpress and Google Analytics?

Comment: I may be overthinking it. Can I just add an arbitrary parameter to the url like: 
    http://example.com?id=1
and then look for that in my Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be building your own url for each user. I would build a url first with this link, then write a script or something to create a unique url for each user in your contacts list.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Hope that helps!

EDIT: You can also try just adding ?contact_id=99999, visit the link and then go to Google Analytics, look at the live view, and see if your parameter shows up.

Whats Happening Now: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html

Parameters do show up in GA because on most shopping carts each page, product etc have url parameters that are unique, and can be viewed from GA. If it didn't most website applications would not be compatible with GA.

Comment: I tried that and had some friends follow the links. Nothing is showing up in GA though... Looking under Acquisition>Campaigns, there's no data

Comment: Just updated my answer, i would do some testing first, i know for a fact that unique parameters show up in Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks battletoilet, those custom parameters DO show up, but there's a 24 hour delay (which doesn't apply to real-time view). So tracking uniques is as easy as http://example.com/?id=12345